# Excel: How to obtain in which of the sheets I have the maximum rows that meet a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having an excel book with 5 sheets ( one for each year from 2014 to 2019) with the following columns:

[image: Columns of the excel]

I want to put a formula in a cell that answer the following question:

Which year has the most Alfa Romeo diesel cars?

I was thinking to use:

first a counifs function to apply the criteria of the manufacturer and the diesel for each sheet
After that obtain the max of all these values
finally include everything in a set of embebed IF staments likes: If the max is equal to the value I obtained in the sheet 1 the the year is year one, else if the max is equal to the value obtaned in sheet two the year is two and so on.

Of curse it doesn't seems to be a good way to perfom this solution.

I don't want to use VBA.

any idea that helps?

Comment: In which column is the information **diesel vs standard petrol** contained??

Comment: I show only some rows of the sheet. In the fuel typw columns there are some rows that have value "diesel". And in the column manufacturer I have severaal oes also, but I'm interrested ony in Alfa Romeo. Other important thing to know is that each tab willhave its year in the colum year

Comment: It is impossible to answer "Which year has the most Alfa Romeo diesel cars?" with just the data you'd shared. | Hint : try to use countifs() function and share the outcome. update the question with some diesel data would help others to reproduce the case & assist later too.. | On the other hand.. which part of the question that you can answer ? (to breakdown the goal/task)